# How to find stride/padding information of a specific layer in h5 model of tensorflow or keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have been working on extracting convolution layer information from h5 file, which includes neural network model. I have been able to extract information about number of convolution layers in h5 file but I can't see the way to get information about stride size or padding. I have been using h5py to read h5 model.

Here is the code I am using to find number of convolution layers and weights matrix in h5

```
f = h5py.File(weight_file_path)
layers_counter=0
if len(f.attrs.items()):
        print("{} contains: ".format(weight_file_path))
        print("Root attributes:")
        for layer, g in f.items():
           print("  {}".format(layer))
           print("    Attributes:")
           for key, value in g.attrs.items():
               print("      {}: {}".format(key, value))
               print("    Dataset:")
               for p_name in g.keys():
                   param = g[p_name]
                   matrix=param.value #It will be weights matrix
                   matrix_size=a.shape     #It is matrix size
                   if len(matrix_size)>3:
                       layers_counter=layers_counter+1
```

After execution, `layers_counter` will have number of convolution layers.

Comment: I do see, that models that are stored as json has padding and stride information.

Comment: Please include code of what you have tried so far. I think the model configuration is also a json or dict inside the HDF5.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have updated the post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model configuration is stored as a JSON inside the HDF5 file as an attribute of the root dataset, you can get it with this code:

```
import h5py
import json

model_h5 = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

model_config = model_h5["/"].attrs["model_config"]
config_dict = json.loads(model_config)
```

Then you can index into `config_dict` to get the required config params, for example, `config_dict["config"]["layers"][1]["config"]["strides"]` for the first convolutional layer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same thing, here is how i implemented it:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')


for layer in model.layers:
    if "filters" in model.get_layer(name = layer.name).get_config().keys():
        print("layer name: ",layer.name)
        print("strides: ",model.get_layer(name = layer.name).get_config()['strides'])
        print("padding: ",model.get_layer(name = layer.name).get_config()['padding'])
```

which returns all padding and strides for every convolutional layer in model, e.g, layer 1 for resnet50:

```
layer name:  conv1
strides:  (2, 2)
padding:  valid
```

one can also see all configurations with:

```
print("conv configuration: ",model.get_layer(name = layer.name).get_config())
```

you also can use `model.summary()` to get a layer name and substitute it in name parameters, like:

```
print("CONFIG: ",model.get_layer(name = "conv1").get_config())

{'name': 'conv1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'filters': 64, 'kernel_size': (7, 7), 'strides': (2, 2), 'padding': 'valid', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': (1, 1), 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 2.0, 'mode': 'fan_in', 'distribution': 'truncated_normal', 'seed': None, 'dtype': 'float32'}}, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {'dtype': 'float32'}}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}
```